# Limit of multivariable functions Do not understand solution.

Tags: calculus

I have just started looking at limits at multivariable functions and the textbook have provided me with this:

[image]

Now I tried plotting the graph, which made it easier to see the limit.

[image]

However I am not able to see how this is solved. I first of all do not see where the inequality $x^2\leq x^2+y^2$ comes from. As far as Im aware this hold in any given case but is it usual to find such "constructed elements" second I do not see how they have used it in the equation below. Could someone please give a in dept explanation, this is very important that I understand this in depth. PS, studying. g this by myself so do not have a professor to ask!

[image]

I also wonder particularly in part ii) of definition what this actually mean ;$\delta =\delta (\epsilon )$. Cause on right hand side that to me is a function.

Comment: $x^2\le x^2+$ something nonnegative.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant by: as far as I'm aware that holds in any given case"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this kind of inequality is very commonly used. $x^2\leq x^2+1, x^2\leq x^2 + 2, \dots$. When you add something positive, you get a bigger number. So

$$\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \left|\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right| |y|=|y|$$

Then $|y|=\sqrt{y^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

where we used the same kind of inequality.

For the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition, you want your $f(x,y)$ to be within the distance $\epsilon$ of $L$, you have to define the distance of $(x,y)$ to $(a,b)$ to satisfy that. Usually the smaller $\epsilon$ is, the smaller $\delta$ should necessarily be, so that $f(x,y)$ is close enough to $L$. That is why this $\delta$ is dependent on $\epsilon$.

In your above example, the $\delta$ is chosen to be $\epsilon$ itself. But for example, if there was a $2$ in the numerator, you might want to choose $\delta$ to be $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ to satisfy the condition $|f(x,y)-L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Great thank you! Also Im going to update the question a bit. Cause I realise that Im missing something that is directly related to this question. Would you be able add a bit of extra information on top of what you already written in your answer?

Comment: I have updated it now.

Comment: @ALEXANDER: I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ALEXANDER: You are welcome! :) Please see the comment below by SantiagoCanez. I changed the answer a little according to his advice.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that $x \ne 0$ when you use the inequality $1/(x^2+y^2) \le 1/x^2$, since otherwise the term on the right is undefined. This is fine as long as you also say what happens when $x=0$ separately. It would be better to use the given inequality to bound the numerator as: $|x^2||y| \le |x^2+y^2||y|$ to avoid this subtlety.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez: Thank you for pointing that out. I will edit my answer.